# Straight paths Dijkstra’s Algorithm implementation

Tags: javascript, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

I have recently been trying to implement Dijkstra’s Algorithm in Javascript using the tutorial [here](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html). I'm able to make it go around obstacles successfully, but the paths it makes are simply not optimal, usually coming off as very straight. I think the problem is with how he implemented finding the neighbors. His code seems to pick the neighbors in a near-random order while mine always picks them in a set order, so that's probably a good place to look. I couldn't for the life of me figure it out. I tried everything I could think of.

My filling implementation is this:

```
function floodFill(array,sx,sy,dx,dy){
    var frontier=[[sx,sy]];
    array[sy][sx].visited=true;
    var look=[[-1,0],[0,-1],[1,0],[0,1]];
    var looks=0;
    while(frontier.length>0){
        if(frontier.length>0){
            var current=frontier[0];
            frontier.splice(0,1);
            if(current[0]==dx && current[1]==dy){
                console.log("Broke early!");
                break;
            }
            for(var i=0;i<look.length;i++){
                var y=current[0]+look[i][0];
                var x=current[1]+look[i][1];
                if((y>=0 && y<array[current[0]].length) && (x>=0 && x<array.length)){
                    if(array[y][x].visited==false && array[y][x].type==0){
                        frontier.push([y,x]);
                        looks++;
                        array[y][x].visited=true;
                        array[y][x].origin=[current[0],current[1]];
                        array[y][x].order=looks;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can find a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8xkdez/3/) (you need to open up your javascript console to see it)

Thank you very much for your time.

Here's an image of my problem
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer. To put it simply, I wasn't checking diagonals when I was finding the neighbors.

[You can find a working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/tr8xkdez/4/)

The part that I changed

```
var look=[[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1]];
```